# How to make face image scramble?

Tags: matlab

I want to scramble a face image. I don't know which command in matlab programming will make my face scramble. Would you please indicate me?

and now I want to scramble it by shuffling its pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine [randperm](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) and [reshape](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html), like this:

```
img = reshape(img(randperm(numel(img))), size(img));
```

**Alternative solution: "Scramble by pixel blocks"**

You could do it like this:

```
img = imread('http://www.ricbit.com/uploaded_images/lena-713374.jpg');

blockSize = 64;

nRows = size(img, 1) / blockSize;
nCols = size(img, 2) / blockSize;
scramble = mat2cell(img, ones(1, nRows) * blockSize, ones(1, nCols) * blockSize, size(img, 3));
scramble = cell2mat(reshape(scramble(randperm(nRows * nCols)), nRows, nCols));

subplot(1,2,1), imshow(img); title('Source image');
subplot(1,2,2), imshow(scramble); title('Scrambled image');
```

Where `blockSize` is the width and height of the block, in pixels (ex.: 64 x 64)

**Note:** blockSize MUST be a common factor of the original image width AND height values.

Comment: what is img and nume1?would you plz explain

Comment: Sure. `img` would be the matrix containing the face image, and `numel` is a Matlab function which gives the number of elements of a matrix.

Comment: I've run your mentioned code, but the result was something like white noise or random dot

Comment: Well, you said you wanted to scramble the image by shuffling it's pixels. That's what it does, the result will be like noise, though.

Comment: yes, but what I want is make the face scrambled it means forexample lips will be in the place of noise and vise versa, or we have eyes at the down and....it means that I want to shuffle pixels of images not to make random dot

Comment: The code I provided doesn't create 'random dots', it really shuffles pixels. Perhaps you would like to shuffle "pixel blocks", like dividing your image into blocks of 50x50 pixels, and shuffling the blocks. There is a script on File Exchange that does just that. You could try it: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17981-randblock